# get time from string, date from today

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

How do I get the time from a string and the date from today?

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("7:30PM", "%I:%M%p")
```

Gives me a `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 19, 30)`, but I'd like it to have today's date and year.

Comment: In what format would exactly?

Comment: @TobiasP what do you mean?

Comment: I didn't understand the format you where looking for. Something like [day][year] or [day], [month], [year] ? please give an example

Comment: @TobiasP I just want a datetime.datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible option is [combine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime("7:30PM", "%I:%M%p").time()

datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today().date(), t)
```

output:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 27, 19, 30)
```